# Manjaro Emergency Shell After Update

Tags: boot, manjaro

I am getting emergency shell after an update on Manjaro with this message:

```
Warning: /lib/modules/5.10.2-2-MANJARO/modules.Ed name not found - ignoring
mount: /new_root: unknown filesystem type ‘ext4’
you are now being dropped into an emergency shell
sh: cant access tty; job control turned off
```

I can not type anything in this emergency shell and I can not access my boot menu to boot from live usb. ASRock motherboard is f8 or f10 key, neither those nor del key will bring me into boot menu so I am stuck with this shell. Ive tried googling, searching reddit, SE, etc and have not been able to get anywhere with this. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Can't type anything to even try the answer below. Did you figure anything out?

Comment: Held ESC while booting to get to the GRUB menu, then to adv options and was able to boot into kernel 5.9. The answer below helped from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot with an older kernel version and the reinstall kernel510

pacman -S linux510

It worked after this for me.